# How to create clickable hyperlinks in a skype message?

Tags: skype, hyperlink

I am wondering if there is a way to send clickable hyperlinks in Skype messages.

I tried this:

```
<a href=http://www.example.com">click here</a>
```

but it didn't turn into a link.

Is there some way of doing this??

Answer (score 2):

Same as GitHub / Reddit markup: [click here]([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))

(To clarify, example.com is not a link containing information about Skype markup; it is part of the markup example.  I don't have a link pointing to Skype markup documentation on hyperlinks because I couldn't find any webpage documenting the behavior I just described, other than that I have tried it myself and it works.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You don't create hyperlinks. Just send `http://www.example.com` and skype will generate an icon automagically for the other person to click

Comment: thanks! I know this much.. we are trying to share some text from our mobile application on skype.. if the text contains html elements, they are not processed.. we are using branch.io deeplinking

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround:
add link to word document, hit enter and then from the context menu copy it as a hyperlink then send on skype.